# Concatenating the symbol in recordset of a PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, recordset

In my record set I am taking countrycode using GET operator and sending it to the query as a parameter and I am using LIKE operator for this query like this.

```
$query_getzone = "SELECT distinct LocationId FROM all_dropdown WHERE LocationId LIKE '".$country.".'-%'";
```

I am getting an error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-%'' at line 1'.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Try this `LIKE '".$country."-%'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
$query_getzone =  "SELECT distinct LocationId FROM all_dropdown WHERE LocationId LIKE '$country-%'";;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given extra (dot) `.` and (quote) `'` in the concatenation

remove it and it will be as : `LIKE '".$country."-%'`

and so whole query becomes :

```
$query_getzone = "SELECT distinct LocationId FROM all_dropdown WHERE LocationId LIKE '".$country."-%'";
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have extra quote(') and a dot (.) in query.

Change like this:

```
"... WHERE LocationId LIKE '" . addslashes($country) . "-%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query_getzone = "SELECT distinct LocationId FROM all_dropdown WHERE LocationId LIKE ". "'$country-%'";
```

will work.